# for loops nested array output

Tags: javascript, nested

Part of my homework I have to write a program that calculates all multiplication tables up to 10 and store the results in an array. The first entry formatting example is "1 x 1 = 1".
I think I have my code written right for the nested for loop but I'm not sure on how to output it properly.

```
var numOne = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var numTwo = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var multiple = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numOne.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < numTwo.length; j++) {
    multiple.push(numOne[i] * numTwo[j]);
    console.log(numOne[i] * numTwo[j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: var numOne = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var numTwo = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var multiple = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numOne.length; i++) {
    document.writeln("<br />");
  for (var j = 0; j < numTwo.length; j++) {
    multiple.push(numOne[i] * numTwo[j]);
    //console.log(numOne[i] * numTwo[j]);
    document.write(numOne[i] * numTwo[j] + " ");
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a template string, and you can just loop through the numbers in the arrays without using arrays (in the same way you were looping through the indices):

```js
var multiple = [];
var m;

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
    m = i * j;
    multiple.push(m);
    console.log(`${i} * ${j} = ${m}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: "just one of them"... or no arrays at all

Answer (score 1):

```
var multiple = [];
var first = 1;
var last = 10;

for (var i = first; i <= last; i++) {
  for (var j = first; j <= last; j++) {
    multiple.push(i + " x " + j + " = " + (i*j));
    console.log(multiple[multiple.length-1]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if ES6 is part of your curriculum, so here is how to do it with and without template literals

```
// Create the arrays that you want to multiply

var numOne = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var numTwo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

// Create a function that accepts both arrays as arguments
function multiply(arr1, arr2) {
  var products = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
        //Here we are using template literals to format the response, so that the program will show you the inputs and calculate the answer
      products.push(`${arr1[i]} X ${arr1[j]} = ${arr1[i] * arr2[j]}`); 
      /* If ES6 is outside of the curriculum, the older method for formatting would be like this:
        products.push(arr1[i] + " X " + arr2[j] + " = " + arr1[i]*arr2[j])
      */
    }
  }
  console.log(products);
  return products;
}

// Call the second function example
multiply(numOne, numTwo);
```